# How to copy a tag element from Browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am trying to copy some specific tag elements from the browser but it copies the entire child tags too.

I tried to use the "Copy Element" and other options but no luck.
Tried with different browsers and same result.

How to copy a specific element from browser such as a div tag without copying the related tags with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to copy child elements will also get copied. There is no specific option to only copy the tag element without copying its child.

You can try to refer to the steps below may helpful to copy tag element using the **MS Edge Chromium browser**.

1. Visit the desired site.
2. Open the **developer tools** by pressing the **F12** key.
3. Find and click on the desired tag element to select it.
4. Right click on that tag element and click on **Edit as HTML** option.

[image]

5. It will show the code in edit mode like below.

[image]

6. You can select and copy the desired part of the code and paste it in other apps.

[image]